# Symfony2 : Unrecognized option "admin" under "security.providers.in_memory.memory"

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-forms, symfony-2.7

I have this problem when I trying to

> **php app/console server:run**

it show me this error :

Unrecognized option "admin" under "security.providers.in_memory.memory"

and this is my **security.yml**

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        Custom\CMSBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER]
    providers:
        chain_providers:
            chain:
                providers: [in_memory, user_db]
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                admin: { password: adminpass, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        user_db:
            entity: { class: CustomCMSBundle:User, property: username }
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: /.*
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
                default_target_path: /
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /
            security: true
            anonymous: true
    access_control:
            - { path: /login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: /cms/user, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
            - { path: /.*, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Comment: `admin` should be indented behind `users` (4 more spaces)

Comment: Thanks it's **working** now

Comment: @AndreaGhidini Please add an answer. Your answer should by all means be marked as accepted ;)

Comment: @JovanPerovic answer added, with this simple answers I never know if I should comment or add an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The defined users (`admin` in this case) should be defined inside the `users` map and so have to be indented more than `users`:

```
in_memory:
    memory:
        users:
            admin: { password: adminpass, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```